# local admin vs domain admin on a domain controller

Tags: group-policy, domain, password

I would like to create a group policy to set a specific password for all local administrator users. Now even though you can't manage local users on a domain controller ("This snap-in cannot be used on a domain controller"), even on a DC, the local and domain admins are distinct entities, right? So if I set up my group policy, it won't affect the domain admin passwords, right? But if I link this GP to the whole domain, it will affect the local admin password on the DC, which, if demoted, will matter, right?

The GP I'm planning to use: Computer configuration, Preferences, Control Panel Settings, Local users and groups, local user, update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A DC doesn't have a local Administrator account (or any other local user account); if/when you demote it, the demotion process will ask you for a new password for the newly-created local Administrator user.

Be careful, though: depending on the specific way you use to set the password, it *could* affect the domain Administrator if the GPO gets applied to a DC.

Comment: I updated the post and named the GP. Are you saying the local accounts are deleted when you promote a machine to a DC? Aren't they only inactivated, made unusable, and can be later reactivated?

Comment: @fejesjoco - They are deleted.

Comment: @fejesjoco: when you promote the *first* DC and create a domain, all local accounts on the server become domain accounts (including Administrator). When you promote an *additional* DC into an existing domain, all local accounts are deleted (the promotion wizard even warns you about this).

Comment: Okay, so, now that I mentioned which GP I'm talking about, it shouldn't touch the domain admin, even if applied on the DC, right?

Comment: @fejesjoco: right, that setting simply doesn't apply to domain controllers.